# How to get table row count in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

There's a requirement where I need to get the table row count information without using count function. Currently I have used the below code to achieve it:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(schemas.name, '.', tables.name) as tableName, 
    partitions.rows AS tableRowCount
FROM
    sys.partitions
JOIN
    sys.tables ON tables.object_id = partitions.object_id
JOIN
    sys.schemas ON tables.schema_id = schemas.schema_id
```

But for some reason, this query is not working properly as expected. Having said that, in some cases tableRowCount is different if the same is checked using the count function.

Is there a way to overcome this challenge?

Please note I tried using `sys.dm_db_partition_stats` table as well.

However, I get this error:

> Msg 104385, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
> Catalog view 'dm_db_partition_stats' is not supported in this version.

Please help.

Comment: Are you *sure* you're using the *completely* unsupported versions SQL Server 2008 ***and*** 2008R2? I'm pretty sure `dm_db_partition_stats` was added in SQL Server 2008. It's in Azure Synapse and Parallelel Warehouse that you can't call it under that name (it's still supported though, under a different name as noted in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-partition-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)).

Comment: @Larnu - Not sure about the version. Currently, it is restricted only for Admin users. I just have viewing rights to the DB

Comment: Run `PRINT @@VERSION`. I've removed the version tags, and it seems pretty clear you *aren't* using those versions (if you are, you shouldn't be, they've been completely unsupported for over **2 years**).

Comment: The row counts stored in the DMVs are approximate and are not maintained in real-time, so in an active database there could be some lag between the live `count` and these stored values.

Comment: @Stu - In some of the tables, I saw the count was over 12M but in the sys tables it was 0 since yesterday itself. Do you think, whether there is a specific time when the sys tables usually get refreshed ?

Comment: @Larnu - Microsoft Azure SQL Data Warehouse - 10.0.13657.0 Aug 11 2021 22:23:36 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. Apologies my bad. I think mistakenly I have added 2008 version in the tags.

Comment: *"Microsoft Azure SQL Data Warehouse "* There we go, that's why you can't reference `dm_db_partition_stats`, because you can't in that version; it's under a different object name (see the documentation I linked earlier).

Comment: @Larnu - Yeah just saw. It gave me `User does not have permission to perform this action.`

Comment: I could only speculate, you would have to experiment, it might be related to index rebuild  or statistics updates, if these haven't been done on a table since server restart perhaps that may be why.

Answer (score 0):

This should be much faster than using `COUNT`.

```sql
SELECT SUM(p.rows) FROM sys.partitions AS p
INNER JOIN sys.tables AS t ON p.[object_id] = t.[object_id]
INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s ON s.[schema_id] = t.[schema_id]
WHERE t.name = N'(yourtable)' AND s.name = N'dbo' AND p.index_id IN (0,1);
```

Note that this approach is in no way portable between RDBMSs.

Comment: The OP is already using `sys.partitions` as stated in the question.

Comment: @AlexandervanOostenrijk - Using this code as well it is giving me same result as mine. This is different if I do a count(*) on the same table. Any idea?